# Was Molière’s “Misanthrope” inspired by Menander’s “Dyskolos”?

Tags: french-language, moliere, menander, the-misanthrope, dyskolos

The 4th century BCE comedy *Dyskolos* (“Old Cantankerous”) by Menander was rediscovered in Egypt in the mid-20th century. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyskolos) on the play tells us:

> The *Dyskolos* inspired Molière, who knew only the theme of the play, as it had not yet been found, in his writing of *The Misanthrope* (1666).<sup>[not verified in body]</sup>

Is it the case that Molière’s *Misanthrope* was inspired by Menander’s *Dyskolos*, and if so, what sources did Molière draw on for his knowledge of Menander’s theme?